# Are median and mode also 'moments' of a probability distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, descriptive-statistics

Wikipedia describes 'moments' as quantitative measures related to the shape of a function's/distribution's graph. In that case, are median and mode also essentially a form of moments? If not, why not?

Answer (score 2):

No.  That is just a general description; the mathematical definition (which explains in more detail what is meant by the description) is given in the article:

$$\mu_n = \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty (x - c)^n f_X(x) \, dx.$$

After all, "quantitative measures related to the shape of a function" is not mathematically precise.  That could refer to anything--convexity, monotonicity, supremum, etc.

The notions of median and mode are more aptly categorized as "[measures of central tendency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_tendency)."